# How to save a structural text document to a table in sql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, word-template

I am doing a project where I need to be able to save/load a structural text document (like MS word) to/from a table in mysql.

For example, if someone gives me a sample document like sample.doc, I should be able to save the content as well as format into a sql table. Then at another web page, I should be able to load the sample document from the table so end user can start from there. The end user can then modify the sample document and then save it as a real specific document.

Anyone has some idea on how this could be achieve with php/javascript/html?

thanks!

---

Let me clarify my question a bit. The requirement is that the user needs to document some notes based on pre-defined text templates (like word templates). This is a web-based application. I want to provide an option for the user to be able to load a certain template, then the user will only modify a few lines of the template and save that specific document. I was initially thinking how to store the template and specific document in sql tables but not sure how to do that. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: So you're asking how to create Google Docs? Too Broad

Comment: OregonTrail - I've kind of clarify my question a bit. Hope that makes some more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard HTML file upload to upload the file.  Best to store nonrelational data like the file content itself in S3/ cloud storage or on the filesystem rather than in a relational database ( you'll never join or query on the content of the file, so it doesn't belong in an RDS) but if you *need* to, put it in a BLOB column.

I recommend storing filename and MIME type, if you can determine, in the database - that's relational data.

Then it's just a question of building an interface to search out the sample document to start from, and download it.  You'll want to use the Content-Type and Attachment Disposition headers to make sure the user can download the file.

OF course if you expect to *interpret* the file yourself, and provide an online editor, that is going to be way more difficult (@OregonTrail's comment applies in that case).  But as long as it's just upload file, save file, find file, download file, LAMP should be good for that.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks Dan. I will try to think about this more. Obviously my initial thought is a bit naive.